# How to make page layout dynamic based on dependent picklist fields?

Tags: lightning-web-components, process-builder, dynamic, visual-flows

I have a scenario that based on few dependant picklist fields, the page layout/fields in the page layout gets changed. Is it possible to do it using any declarative method or dynamic forms or flows or LWC+Flows?

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious approach is to use [Dynamic Forms](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_lab_dynamic_forms.htm) which goes [GA in Winter '21](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_forcecom_lab_dynamic_forms_ga.htm). Using this functionality you can conditionally show individual fields or field sections using "visibility rules".

You need to be careful to ensure that universally required (i.e. required at the schema level) fields are always visible.

Individual fields can be shown or not using a visibility rule that can use other fields' values, where the rule is evaluated when those other values change (the rules are applied "dynamically"). This isn't the case with field sections; their visibility is only updated on opening the form and after save. You can find more details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_page_components_visibility.htm&type=5).

Comment: does it work for record creation using "New" button ?

Comment: Give it a try for yourself.

Comment: Yeah that works

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is possible. make a custom LWC comp, [read the fields on the record with wire](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_example) and render the data using [getters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_props_getter) for the [conditional sections](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_conditional) and a [record form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation).